# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_2^x M(t)\cdot f'(t)dt$, where $M(x)$ is Mertens functions

Tags: integration, limits, summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mu(n)$ the **Möbius function**. I know that combining **Abel summation formula**, the **Prime Number Theorem** and **l'Hôpital's rule** I can deduce $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\mu(n)\cdot\frac{\log\log n}{{\log\log (n+1)}}= 0-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_2^x M(t)\cdot f'(t)dt,$$
where $M(x)$ is the **Mertens function**, and $f(x)=\frac{\log\log x}{{\log\log (x+1)}}$. I know that $M(t)$ can be bounded by the obvious $t$, thus RHS should be

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}O\left(\int_2^x \frac{(t+1)\log(t+1)\cdot\log\log(t+1)-t\log t\cdot\log\log t)}{(t+1)\log t\cdot\log(t+1)\cdot\log^2\log(t+1)}dt\right).$$

> **Question.** Is there a reasonable way to compute (or compute improving my bound for Mertens function without additional more tedious computations) the limit in RHS? I say, if it is possible, determine if there is convergence and, if there is a limit compute it without do the more hardest computations. **Thanks in advance.**

Now with the **BOUNTY** I am looking an approach that provide us the behaviour of the first series, thus RHS, thus if it neccesary tedious computations your answer will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: My goal with this exercise is to know with more or less precission how work with a situation of this kind, and if it is possible impove the bound for **Mertens function** that I've used, but it isn't neccesary give the more best result. The more important is that I want to know how work easily, if it is possible, with complicated functions doing easy computations. Thanks

Comment: I ask: It is possible to get a bound or an asymptotic quickly, without the more tedious computations, and compute the asymptotic behaviour of RHS correctly? If there is a limit od RHS, **comopute it in the sense that say if at least is finite or $\infty$, since I know that we are work with the bound encoded in the big oh notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that holds $$\frac{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}{\log\left(\log\left(n+1\right)\right)}\sim1$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ so your sum is very close to $M\left(x\right)$. Then $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\mu\left(n\right)\frac{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}{\log\left(\log\left(n+1\right)\right)}\sim\frac{1}{x}\sum_{2\leq n\leq x}\mu\left(n\right)=\frac{1}{x}\left(M\left(x\right)-1\right)\rightarrow0$$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ since PNT is equivalent to $$\frac{M\left(x\right)}{x}\stackrel{x\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$ Maybe it's interesting to claim a related result which can be found in the [Terence Tao blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/the-bourgain-sarnak-ziegler-orthogonality-criterion/) (with the references).

> **Proposition:** Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}
>  $ be a bounded function such that $$\sum_{n\leq x}f\left(pn\right)\overline{f\left(qn\right)}=o_{p,q}\left(x\right)
>  $$ for any distinct $p,q$ prime numbers, then $$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu\left(n\right)f\left(n\right)=o\left(x\right).$$

Comment: Very thanks much, you make that learn mathematics to be easy. Very thanks much for the reference. Can you add in a comment a definition for $o_{p,q}(x)$ or a toy example of use of the proposition?

Comment: @user243301 My pleasure. With $o_{p,q}(x)$ I intend that the decay rate of the error term may depend on $p$ and $q$. An example, from the blog of Tao, is $$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)e^{2\pi i\alpha n}=o(x)$$ where $\alpha$ is irrational. I forgot to explain that $p,q$ are prime numbers.

Comment: Very thanks much.